# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.STAFF, DRIVER=4.22.29

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I have database DB2 SAMPLE in server 10.74.44.65:51020
I'm trying connect to staff table in database but i got an exception.
I use db2jcc4 of IBM.

```
Connection successfully
Test 1
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.STAFF, DRIVER=4.22.29
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ld.a(ld.java:810)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ld.a(ld.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ld.a(ld.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.up.c(up.java:2796)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.up.d(up.java:2784)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.up.a(up.java:2212)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.i(bb.java:148)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.b(bb.java:41)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.vb.i(vb.java:145)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.up.lb(up.java:2181)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.up.a(up.java:3300)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.up.a(up.java:717)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.up.executeQuery(up.java:696)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

My Java Code. 10.74.44.65 is location ip of server .
Database connected but i cannot execute sql query.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Connection conn;
        Statement  stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://10.74.44.65:51020/SAMPLE","db2admin","Us3admin");
            System.out.println("Connection successfully");
            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Test 1");
            rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from staff");
            System.out.println("Test 2");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Employee number = " + rs.getString(1));
              }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? I am currently facing the exact problem, and I suspect the fact that my user is not granted with the appropriate rights to access those table (since I am prefixing it with the appropriate name). As soon as I will fix it maybe I can tip you out.

Answer (score 0):

> "SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704" is a DB2 error code indicating '**object does not exist**'

<sup>(source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21613531).</sup>

`SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.STAFF` then means that table `STAFF` does not exist in fro user `DB2ADMIN`, or the user is not authorized for that table.

Comment: I tried but still error :(